# How to change the selected ListTile Icon and Text color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

By default when an item is selected in the drawer it is currently **blue** (see the picture below), where is this color property coming from, and is it possible to change it directly? I am using `ListTile()` ; for the background there is a property called `selectedTileColor` but, I cannot find anything for the foreground.

```
 int _selectedDestination = 0;

 ListTile(
   leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
   title: const Text('Home'),
   selected: _selectedDestination == 0,
   onTap: () => selectDestination(0),
  ),


 void selectDestination(int index) {
   setState(() {
     _selectedDestination = index;
   });
 }
```

[image: Drawer]

Comment: The color comes from `primarySwatch` inside `ThemeData` - `theme:` under `MaterialApp`. If you don't want to change theme data, you can use the answers to individually change the list tile. Else, you can change the primary color.

Comment: Please, Describe problem in better way to understand what you are trying to say.!

Answer (score 0):

you can do by wrapping ListTile in an Ink as:

```
Ink(
  color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
  child: ListTile(title: Text('hello')),
)
```

OR using SelectedTileColor

```
ListTile(
  selected: true,
  selectedTileColor: Colors.brown,
  tileColor: Colors.black,
  title: const Text(
  'Title',
 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
 ),
)
```

Comment: Please note, the `OR` part of your answer changes the tile background.

Comment: The text part of the code is for the Icon.

Comment: Exactly, that does not change when the tile is selected since it is a constant and therefore does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change selected icon and text color to red or every color you want:

```
 ListTile(
   leading: Icon(Icons.home , color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent),
   title: const Text('Home' , style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent)),
   selected: _selectedDestination == 0,
   onTap: () => selectDestination(0),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the most efficient way to do it according to the docs. So you just need to wrap your `ListTile()` in a `ListTileTheme()` and then use the `selectedColor:`  property, and then put your ListTile in the `child:`  property like so `child: ListTile()`

Finally we obtain something like this:

```
    ListTileTheme(
      selectedColor: Colors.red,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.add),
        title: const Text('New Item'),
        selected: _selectedDestination == 1,
        onTap: () => selectDestination(1),
      )),
```

Check the docs for more info: [ListTileTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileTheme-class.html)